# How do I work with Apple OSX API with Delphi?

Tags: macos, api, delphi, usb

I am confused regarding how to know what to do in order to utilize the OSX API to do whatever I want my app to do.

For example, I'd like to work with USB devices, where can I find info regarding that?

I have asked previously regarding just that, USB devices, but no one answered, and google search gives me air-thin results.

I don't know how to approach this.

Where can I find documentations or instructions or tutorials or whatever that helps me understand the OSX API implementation with Delphi?

I use Delphi XE7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The official reference for the OSX API is located  in the [`Mac Developer Library`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/), for usb devices you can check [`OSX USB Device Interface Guide`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/USBBook/USBOverview/USBOverview.html).

Now the best place to learn how work with the OSX from Delphi is reading the RTL OSX code located in the  `Embarcadero\Studio\n.0\source\rtl\osx` folder.  Another great source of information is the [`TIndex`](http://www.tindex.net/) site which is a huge collection of ordered and selected resources about Delphi programming, So you can try the [`OSX Section`](http://www.tindex.net/OSX/index.html).